# How to fix ASP.NET MVC User Interface wrong inputs applied. ASP.NET Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

How to fix this UI, I need to see checkboxes instead of textboxes. I have defined inputs for checkboxes but still textboxes are shown. I am using ASP.NET Identity - MVC 5

Here is my running-app the textboxes should be checkboxes.
[image]

View:

```
@using Fst.ReactDemoApplication.Web.Models
@model List<ManageUserRolesViewModel>
@{
     ViewData["Title"] = "Manage";
     Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<form method="post">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            <h2>Manage User Roles</h2>
            Add/Remove Roles for User / @ViewBag.UserName.
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
            {
                <div class="form-check m-1">
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[i].RoleId" />
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[i].RoleName" />
                    <input asp-for="@Model[i].Selected" class="form-check-input" />
                    <label class="form-check-label" asp-for="@Model[i].Selected">
                        @Model[i].RoleName
                    </label>
                </div>
            }
            <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
            <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary"
                   style="width:auto" />
            <a asp-action="EditUser" asp-route-id="@ViewBag.userId"
               class="btn btn-primary" style="width:auto">Cancel</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Manage(string userId)
{
    ViewBag.userId = userId;
    var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
    if (user == null)
    {
        ViewBag.ErrorMessage = $"User with Id = {userId} cannot be found";
        return View("NotFound");
    }
    ViewBag.UserName = user.UserName;
    var model = new List<ManageUserRolesViewModel>();
    foreach (var role in _roleManager.Roles.ToList())
    {
        var userRolesViewModel = new ManageUserRolesViewModel
        {
            RoleId = role.Id,
            RoleName = role.Name
        };
        if (await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, role.Name))
        {
            userRolesViewModel.Selected = true;
        }
        else
        {
            userRolesViewModel.Selected = false;
        }
        model.Add(userRolesViewModel);
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

**This should be my expected output, is there a way to do this? Thank you**

[image]

Comment: I think `<input asp-for="@Model[i].Selected" class="form-check-input" />` should be `<input type="checkobx" asp-for="@Model[i].Selected" class="form-check-input" />`

Comment: Is `@Model[i].Selected` a `bool`, because that "should just work". A `bool?` will not.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman acutally yes it is a boolean.

Comment: More interesting is that the text fields does not contain any value. There should be true or false as string. Try to print these values in the view as text.

Comment: @Michael - sorry I just got this from a tutorial that I am learning, I'm also quite confuse to it.

Comment: Write <span>@Model[i].Selected</span> inside your loop.

Comment: And check if you are calling the right view from your controller.

Comment: @Michael hello, I tested and it seems accurate because there are true and false value. I got the correct value to it.

Comment: @Michael but adding the checkbox, it won't highlight the value given.

Comment: Unlikely suggestions; Missing `@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers` in view imports. Some other tag helper interfering with MVC's `InputTagHelper`. Some other model metadata causing confusion (https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/9b6afb49f6981de4e242e4781a88caf3804e83e9/src/Mvc/Mvc.TagHelpers/src/InputTagHelper.cs#L490 seems to have other options before trying "bool")

Comment: @JeremyLakeman so should i add tag helper at the very top of my view?

Comment: Probably a bit old, but I've know views to get stuck. Normally a nice IIS reset sorts it all out.